# How to move a Linux software RAID setup from 1 server to another (Debian)

Tags: mdadm

Currently, I have three USB drives running as a RAID-5 set on a Debian-9 server.  All is well.
I would like to safely move them to a different server, running Debian-10.

The host name of the current server is stored in the metadata for that RAID set.  How do I change it to reflect the new server name?

Or am I better off just telling mdadm to ignore host names by using "HOMEHOST ignore" in my mdadm.conf file?

When I move the mdadm.conf file from the old server to the new one, do I leave the name= parameter alone?  Or do I change it to the name of the new host?

Are there any issues with moving the RAID set from Debian 9 to Debian 10?  Possible incompatibilities with the metadata?

One final question.  I assume there is no guarantee that the disks on the old server, /dev/sdb, /dev/sdc, /dev/sdd, will come up with the same names on the new server.  Does mdadm care?

Comment: You should not use RAID5 if data is important to you.

Comment: Please check out SuperUser for home setups. Even so, a RAID5 across USB drives doesn't sound like something you should be running at all if you value your data.

Comment: Thanks for the redirect to SuperUser.  Not a platform I was aware of.

Comment: I'm using RAID5 as the primary leg of my modified 3-2-1 data protection system for a media library.  Seems perfectly appropriate to me.  There is a second copy on a physically district server, backed up daily, and a third copy, off line in a fireproof lockbox, backed up monthly.  While not up to "enterprise" standards, it is a low-cost way of protecting against a number of threats.